# Checking if a column belongs to a provided list

Tags: c#

I've the following code, which checks if one column belongs to the list I provide.  After that, it takes the value contained in it.

I've tried and it's 9 times faster than raising and handling an exception. But I don't find this code very readable.

For example, I don't need to define a variable `drsIDAgentClient`. I've thought of using an extension method over reader and provide a `ColumnExist(string columnName)` method.

Can you see a better solution?

```
DataRow[] drsIDAgentClient = reader.GetSchemaTable().Select("ColumnName = 'IDAgentClient'");
if (drsIDAgentClient.Length > 0)
    coupon.IdAgentClient = reader["IDAgentClient"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (int?)reader["IDAgentClient"];
```

Comment: [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: @Vogel612: ok.. but I really think the meaning wasn't changed. And it sound a bit weird to lose the ownership of a question after posting it online (moderator gets the right to decide at my place on a content I wrote, it's not very intuitive). But I strongly believe in this community and I appreciate especially the work you are doing here on code review.

Comment: I am not a moderator. Also it's more unintuitive to see code in a question and have answers relate to different code IMO..

Comment: @Vogel612: ok.. I've answered myself..

Comment: @Revious Questions and answers on the Stack Exchange sites are owned by the community as a whole. The asker gets some limited extra privileges (able to edit/comment on their question regardless of rep; able to delete if there's no answers; getting to select a correct answer). Everything else, however, is owned by the community as a whole, hence why users of sufficient reputation can suggest edits or edit outright.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: thanks, I know.. even if it's not very intuitive and could not be perceived as something fair. Some other website use a similar politic on images and there were a lot of protests. However in the specific case is not a problem, I'm simply saying that something which is by law can be perceived as strongly bad. But this community seems to have reached a good compromise.

Answer (score 14):

> Can you see a better solution?

Yes **use braces** `{}` also for single line statements of an `if` condition.

Using `.Any()` instead of checking `.Length > 0` is faster but only for an `IEnumerable`

I also would enclose `reader["IDAgentClient"] == DBNull.Value` in `()` as it is more readable or even better you can introduce a `boolean isDbNullValue`

```
DataRow[] drsIDAgentClient = reader.GetSchemaTable().Select("ColumnName = 'IDAgentClient'");
if (drsIDAgentClient.Length > 0)
{
    Boolean isDbNullValue = (reader["IDAgentClient"] == DBNull.Value);
    coupon.IdAgentClient = isDbNullValue  ? null : (int?)reader["IDAgentClient"];
}
```

---

After rereading your question it seems that you want to know if a **column with a specific name** exists in the `SchemaTable`.

So you can use instead of the code above simply this

```
String columnName = "IDAgentClient";
if (reader.GetSchemaTable().Columns.Contains(columnName))
{
    Boolean isDbNullValue = (reader[columnName] == DBNull.Value);
    coupon.IdAgentClient = isDbNullValue  ? null : (int?)reader[columnName];
}
```

I would like to expand @Malachi's answer with not using a tenary

Malachi's check

> ```
> bool IsColumnEmpty(string columnName)
> {
>     return reader.GetSchemaTable().Columns.Contains(columnName)) 
>         ? Reader[columnName] == DBNull.Value 
>         : true;
> }
> ```

can be rewritten like

```
bool ColumnHasValue(string columnName)
{
    return reader.GetSchemaTable().Columns.Contains(columnName) && 
           Reader[columnName] != DBNull.Value;        
}
```

and if you really need to use an extension method you can do this like

```
public static class HelperExtension
{
    public static bool ColumnHasValue(this IDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {
        return reader.GetSchemaTable().Columns.Contains(columnName) && 
               Reader[columnName] != DBNull.Value; 
    }
}
```

and call it

```
coupon.IdAgentClient = reader.ColumnHasValue(columnName) ? (int?)reader[columnName] : null;
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, `.Length` is faster than `Any` because Length is already calculated versus `Any` which has to do calculations. `Any` is faster than `Count() > 0` though

Comment: And always remember, `Yes use braces {} also for single line statements of an if condition.` is only an opinion. It can be helpful, but it is not part of every coding standard.

Answer (score 6):

I am going to extend Steve's answer a little bit as I see something that would make his code short and to the point.  I think Heslacher hit on Ternary statements as well.

in Steve's answer he has this

```
String columnName = "IDAgentClient";
bool columnEmpty = IsColumnEmpty(columnName);

if (columnEmpty)
{
    coupon.IdAgentClient = null;
}
else
{
    coupon.IDAgentClient = (int?)reader[columnName];
}
```

that utilizes this method

```
bool IsColumnEmpty(string columnName)
{
    if (reader.GetSchemaTable().Columns.Contains(columnName))
    {
        return reader[columnName] == DBNull.Value;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

first thing is inside of the boolean method

I think you can utilize a Ternary here as well.

```
bool IsColumnEmpty(string columnName)
{
    return reader.GetSchemaTable().Columns.Contains(columnName)) 
        ? Reader[columnName] == DBNull.Value 
        : true;
}
```

and then with Steve's main bit of code you don't need to actually declare a boolean variable or that bulky if/then statement either, use a ternary like this.

```
String columnName = "IDAgentClient";
coupon.IdAgentClient = IsColumnEmpty(columnName) 
    ? null
    : (int?)reader[columnName];
```

If you understand ternary operators, then this is pretty clear and straightforward.

Again this is only looking at Steve's answer...

Answer (score 5):

Heslacher did a great job cleaning it up, I still think it could still be cleaned up more though:

```
String columnName = "IDAgentClient";
bool columnEmpty = IsColumnEmpty(columnName);

if (columnEmpty)
{
    coupon.IdAgentClient = null;
}
else
{
    coupon.IDAgentClient = (int?)reader[columnName];
}
```

Then have a separate method:

```
bool IsColumnEmpty(string columnName)
{
    if (reader.GetSchemaTable().Columns.Contains(columnName))
    {
        return reader[columnName] == DBNull.Value;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Arguably you could also separate out checking if it exists and if it's empty.

Comment: Hey Steve I extended your answer a little bit....I hope you don't mind...

Comment: I don't mind at all! I personally prefer not to use ternary operators but it's a good idea to expose people to everything and let them decide :)

Answer (score 1):

I've thought of using Extension Methods to being near to SRP and splitting the source code in a reusable part plus a specific part.

```
if(reader.ColumnExists("TournamentName"))
{
   odd.Championship = (string)reader["TournamentName"];
}

public static class HelperExtension
{
    public static bool ColumnExists(this IDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {
        DataRow[] rows = reader.GetSchemaTable().Select(string.Format("ColumnName = '{0}'", columnName));
        return rows.Length > 0;
    }
}
```